# How do I get the source for my events, with Bootstrap 3 DateTimePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using [Bootstrap 3 DateTimePicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) but having some minor issues.

Basically, on the dp.show event, how do I get the source control? As far as I can tell, there is no parameter sent with the event, so I'm having a hard time figuring out which control actually showed.

(I have many pickers in my application)

Standard JQuery would tell me I could use e.Target, but there is no e sent with the event :(

How do I handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach a handler to your datepicker collection

```
$('.datepicker').on('dp.show', function() {
    // this here will refer to the currently showing widget
    console.log(this);
});
```

This is the standard bootstrap way of dealing with events.

EDIT: if you read the source code, the event is bound to the element with which the datepicker is initialized: https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/blob/master/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js#L451

Answer (score 1):

you can use events like below

```html
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="/css/result-light.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //&lt;![CDATA[
    $(function() {
      $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker();

      $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.show", function(e) {
        console.log(e);// e is event and use console to explore other options
      });
    }); //]]&gt;
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="input-group ">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datetimepicker6">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```